# android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class ScannerFragment that is not a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, classcastexception

I updated a few libraries in app.gradle like support library from 22.2.0 -> 23.0.0 and versions of few third party libraries, and now I'm getting the following runtime error in one particular activity:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook/com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.AddBooksActivity_}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #155: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #155: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.AddBooksActivity_.setContentView(AddBooksActivity_.java:56)
            at com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.AddBooksActivity.onCreate(AddBooksActivity.java:140)
            at com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.AddBooksActivity_.onCreate(AddBooksActivity_.java:46)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.Fragments.ScannerFragment that is not a Fragment
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:606)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2110)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5348)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                at com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.AddBooksActivity_.setContentView(AddBooksActivity_.java:56)
                at com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.AddBooksActivity.onCreate(AddBooksActivity.java:140)
                at com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.AddBooksActivity_.onCreate(AddBooksActivity_.java:46)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:606)
                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2110)
                at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5348)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                at com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.AddBooksActivity_.setContentView(AddBooksActivity_.java:56)
                at com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.AddBooksActivity.onCreate(AddBooksActivity.java:140)
                at com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.AddBooksActivity_.onCreate(AddBooksActivity_.java:46)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

In particular this line seems strange:

```
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.Fragments.ScannerFragment that is not a Fragment
```

( ScannerFragment is a fragment that implements dm77 barcode scanner which i updated from 1.7.2 to 1.8.2 )

Scanner Fragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zbar.BarcodeFormat;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zbar.Result;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zbar.ZBarScannerView;


public class ScannerFragment extends Fragment implements MessageDialogFragment.MessageDialogListener,
        ZBarScannerView.ResultHandler, FormatSelectorDialogFragment.FormatSelectorDialogListener,
        CameraSelectorDialogFragment.CameraSelectorDialogListener {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle state) {
        mScannerView = new ZBarScannerView(getActivity());

        //stuff
        return mScannerView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state){
        super.onCreate(state);
       //stuff

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        //stuff
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        //stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //stuff

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        //stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        //stuff
    }



    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //stuff

}
```

XML Snippet:

```
<FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/flScan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/fScanner"
                    class="com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.Fragments.ScannerFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:padding="12dp">


                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/ibAutofocus"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ripple_light"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:contentDescription="Enable / Disable Autofocus"
                        android:longClickable="true"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_auto_focus_on" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/ibFlashControl"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ibAutofocus"
                        android:background="@drawable/ripple_light"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:contentDescription="Enable / Disable Flash"
                        android:longClickable="true"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_image_flash_off" />


                </RelativeLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It feels like `AppCompatActivity` is trying to use native fragments instead of the backport, and `ScannerFragment` is using the backport.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you mean v4 support for fragments? I'm only targeting Icecream Sandwich + devices... If removing backward compatibility can solve my problem, its totally fine. How do i do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try importing `android.app.Fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` basically don't use support library if you don't need it 'or check that Activity in which you are inflating this fragment about : Whether you are using the `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransaction` from support library only.